# How to rename an .xml file in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, file-rename

I need to edit an .xml document in VBA, and I like to keep the original xml (ppp.xml) and separately the new edited file (which I want to call pppnew.xml), basically without updating the original file. Since I am a basic user, I started with the following piece of code:

```
Sub editxml()

Dim Obj As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim xmlpath As String

Set Obj = New DOMDocument
Obj.async = False
Obj.validateOnParse = False

xmlpath = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ppp.xml"
Obj.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns0='http://update.DocumentTypes.Schema.ppp.Xml'"

If Obj.Load(xmlpath) = True Then
    MsgBox "File XML uploaded"
Else
    MsgBox "File XML not uploaded"
    Exit Sub
End If
        
        'My code follows here
    
Obj.Save xmlpath
End sub
```

I've tried to edit the following line of the code

```
SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns0='http://update.DocumentTypes.Schema.ppp.Xml'
```

By changing it into

```
SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns0='http://pppnew.Xml'
```

But it doesn't work: the code updates the original file, which I want to keep unedited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in fact saving your modifications on the SAME file

Change

```
Obj.Save xmlpath
```

To

```
new_xmlpath = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\new.xml"
Obj.Save new_xmlpath
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to edit the '''SelectionNameSpace''' line too or just let it fixed?

Comment: If the starting xml has not a structure decided by YOU, and the resulting xml keeps respecting the original schema and namespace(s) I suggest you to NOT change that property. I strongly suggest you first learn a bit of what schemas and namespaces are to better grasp how XML works

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you suggest me a good source to start from?